# What percentage a number is out of other number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to work out, for instance what 5% of 200 is, simply by using 200 x 5%..

But what I'm stuck on is how can I work out what percentage a number is of another number?

For example, how can I work out what percentage 68 is out of 309?

I've researched this, but I keep seeing calculations come up with a ":" involved, and I've never seen that used in a calculation before.

Comment: `:` is used in many countries as division symbol instead of `/`

Comment: Okay, that's really _not_ an Excel question, or a software question in general.

Comment: As it stands this is a basic math problem and not a problem with computer hardware or software. If you have an excel formula that does this calculation that you are having trouble understanding then you should edit it into your question or post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Colon ":" is the ratio sign, as well as the division sign in various countries. (Though it has a completely different use in Excel.) So if you have ratios like

> 68 : 309 = x : 100

that's kinda the same as

> <sup>68</sup>⁄<sub>309</sub> = <sup>x</sup>⁄<sub>100</sub>

From that, you get

> <sup>68</sup>⁄<sub>309</sub> · 100 = x

Or in Excel formula,

> `=(68/309)*100`

And the result is ~22%.

Answer (score 1):

what percentage 68 is out of 309?

```
=(68/309)*100
=22%
```

Comment: No, `(68/309)*100` is 22 not 22%. `68/309` is 22%. (0.22 if not formatted as percentage).